# How to get the row value on clicking a link

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with 3 rows, each having hrefs. On click of these links, i need to get the entire value of the row where the link is clicked.

```
Data
Test1_link   image_link   view-link
Test2_link   image_link   view-link
```

the data above are links, on click on any link, its corresponding row value should be rendered.
Can anyone please suggest me on how to achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to get the value of each cell in the row when that row's link is clicked?

Comment: No the cell value, entire row. example, if i click on view link of 1st row, i should get Test1_link as value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a simple script immediately after your table:

```
<script>
  (function (d) {

     // Get the table element
     var table = function() {
       var tables = d.getElementsByTagName('table');
       return tables[tables.length - 1];
     }();

     table.onclick = function (e) {
       var target = e.target;

       // If an <a> was clicked
       if( target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'a' ) {

         // Find the tr containing that a
         var node = target;
         while (node.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'tr' )
           node = node.parentNode;
         var tr = node;

         // Output the contents of the table cells in that row
         var cells = tr.cells;
         for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++ )
             console.log(cells[i].innerHTML);

         // Return false to prevent the link from loading
         return false;
       }
     }
  })(document)
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7xR3/)

Comment: I need the row values, not columns. and each cell will have a link which on click should return entire row value

Comment: @Prajesh That's exactly what this code does. Check the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m7xR3/ . Clicking the top link outputs the entire first row and clicking the bottom link outputs the entire second row.

Comment: Thank you YTowOnt9. It is working. Can you please tell me, why is this not working for an image ? I have image as a link in the 2nd column.

Comment: Hi, I have one more question... Will it work for dynamic table?@YTowOnt9

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jQuery http://www.jquery.com.

```
<table class="js-mytable">
    <tr data-id="23" data-something="you've got it!">
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:;">Test Link</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:;">Image Link</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:;">View Link</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    //run after document ready event
    $(function(){
        //all links in table with class js-mytable
        $('table.js-mytable').on('click','a',function(){
            //var $cell = $(this).parents('td'); //get the parent td of the link
            var $row = $(this).parents('tr'); //get the parent tr of the link
            //get the html5 data attributes from the row
            var id = $row.data('id');
            var something = $row.data('something');

            //do something with the vars
            //alert('Id: '+id+': '+something);

            //get the full html <tr>...</tr>
            //we need to merge it to a new pseudo html element
            //to get the full html with surrounding <tr>
            var html = $('<div>').append($row.clone()).html();
            alert(html);

            return false; //prevent default link action (href)
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you need more details, you need to extend your question...

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ud43

Comment: Sorry, I cannot use jquery. I need that in pure js.

Comment: See @YTowOnt9 answer. It just needs some modifications to get the full row instead of all cell values.

Comment: Maybe also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes would help you. There are examples on how to retrieve the html5 data-* attributes via javascript.